# How does one extract the verb phrase in Spacy?

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

For example:

> Ultimate Swirly Ice Cream Scoopers are usually overrated when one considers all of the scoopers one could buy.

Here I'd like to pluck:

- Subject: "Ultimate Swirly Ice Cream Scoopers"
- Adverbial Clause: "When one considers all of the scoopers one could buy"
- Verb Phrase: "are usually overrated"

---

I have the following functions for `subject`, `object`, and `adverbial clause`:

```
def get_subj(decomp):
    for token in decomp:
        if ("subj" in token.dep_):
            subtree = list(token.subtree)
            start = subtree[0].i
            end = subtree[-1].i + 1
            return str(decomp[start:end])

def get_obj(decomp):
    for token in decomp:
        if ("dobj" in token.dep_ or "pobr" in token.dep_):
            subtree = list(token.subtree)
            start = subtree[0].i
            end = subtree[-1].i + 1
            return str(decomp[start:end])

def get_advcl(decomp):
    for token in decomp:
        # print(f"pos: {token.pos_}; lemma: {token.lemma_}; dep: {token.dep_}")
        if ("advcl" in token.dep_):
            subtree = list(token.subtree)
            start = subtree[0].i
            end = subtree[-1].i + 1
            return str(decomp[start:end])

phrase = "Ultimate Swirly Ice Cream Scoopers are usually overrated when one considers all of the scoopers one could buy."

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
decomp = nlp(phrase)

subj = get_subj(decomp)
obj = get_obj(decomp)
advcl = get_advcl(decomp)

print("subj: ", subj)
print("obj: ", obj)
print("advcl: ", advcl)
```

Output:

```
subj:  Ultimate Swirly Ice Cream Scoopers
obj:  all of the scoopers
advcl:  when one considers all of the scoopers one could buy
```

---

However, the actual `depenency` type `.dep_` for the final word of the VP, "are usually overrated", is "ROOT".

So, the subtree technique fails, as the subtree of `ROOT` returns the entire sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wanting to construct something more like a “verb group” where you keep with the root verb only certain close dependents like `aux`, `cop`, and `advmod` but not ones like `nsubj`, `obj`, or `advcl`.